# Can an Android Service's onDestroy() be called while another member method is running?

Tags: android, thread-safety

I have an Android Service that's going to be accessed by multiple threads. Is it possible that the onDestroy method starts executing while another member method is running on another thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible.

I am pretty sure that after `onDestroy()` all threads associated to an Activity will be interrupted so you will probably end with an `InterruptException` on your running Threads